# How should I make Alt as Ctrl, LWin as Alt, Ctrl as LWin but Ctrl+C as Ctrl+C itself?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap my keys but make an exception of `ctrl+c` being still. I've tried

```
^c::^c

Alt::Control
LWin::Alt
Control::LWin
```

and

```
#c::^c

Alt::Control
LWin::Alt
Control::LWin
```

but none of them work. When I press Ctrl(which is binded to LWin)+C, it still functions as LWin+C.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I need to make sure all the key is left-only. So by doing this

```
LControl::LWin
LWin::LAlt
LAlt::LControl
<^c::Send ^c
```

it works.

Not sure why though.